# RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [672 x 224], m2: [672 x 224]

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

While working on Udacity's AI course I encountered the error in the title.

At first it looks like the image isn't formatted for the model, however the instruction for the course has us format the images using resize, so I get an image dimension of `3x224x224`, that's 3 color channels and 224 pixels by 224 pixels. The image array is in the required dimensions, `[3,224,224]`.

```
Return/Output:
(3, 224, 224)
(3, 224, 224)
torch.Size([1, 3, 224, 224])
```

Next, I figured it was the model, but when I go back, before the training loop and change the original model to fix this error I get a similar error in revers "up stream".

I want this `predict` function to use my model to predict the category of an image.

Posted are:

- Original classifier
- Save checkpoint block
- Process image function
- Predict image function

```python
classifier = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
                      ('fc1', nn.Linear(25088, 500)),
                      ('relu', nn.ReLU()),
                      ('drop', nn.Dropout(0.25)),
                      ('fc2', nn.Linear(500, 102)),
                      ('output', nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1))
                      ]))

model.load_state_dict(state_dict)

checkpoint= {'input_size': 672,
            'output_size': 102,
            'hidden_layers': 224,
            'state_dict': model.state_dict()}

torch.save(checkpoint, 'checkpoint.pth')

def predict(image_path, model, topk=5):
''' Predict the class (or classes) of an image using a trained deep learning model.
'''

model= model.cuda()
model.eval()

# TODO: Implement the code to predict the class from an image file

pil_img= Image.open(image_path)
#print(pil_img)
processed_image= process_image(pil_img)
print(processed_image.shape)
torch_image= torch.from_numpy(processed_image)
torch_image= torch_image.unsqueeze_(0)
print(torch_image.shape)
torch_image= torch_image.float().to('cuda')
output= model.forward(torch_image)
#top_k= predict.topk(topk)
#print(top_k)

return torch_img

image_path = 'flowers/test/8/image_03299.jpg'
predict(image_path, model, 5)


> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-d84c5999ad68> in <module>()
     23 
     24 image_path = 'flowers/test/8/image_03299.jpg'
---> 25 predict(image_path, model, 5)

<ipython-input-21-d84c5999ad68> in predict(image_path, model, topk)
     16     print(torch_image.shape)
     17     torch_image= torch_image.float().to('cuda')
---> 18     output= model.forward(torch_image)
     19     #top_k= predict.topk(topk)
     20     #print(top_k)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
     89     def forward(self, input):
     90         for module in self._modules.values():
---> 91             input = module(input)
     92         return input
     93 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    489             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    490         else:
--> 491             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    492         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    493             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
     53 
     54     def forward(self, input):
---> 55         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
     56 
     57     def extra_repr(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
    992         return torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
    993 
--> 994     output = input.matmul(weight.t())
    995     if bias is not None:
    996         output += bias

    RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-d84c5999ad68> in <module>()
     23 
     24 image_path = 'flowers/test/8/image_03299.jpg'
---> 25 predict(image_path, model, 5)

<ipython-input-21-d84c5999ad68> in predict(image_path, model, topk)
     16     print(torch_image.shape)
     17     torch_image= torch_image.float().to('cuda')
---> 18     output= model.forward(torch_image)
     19     #top_k= predict.topk(topk)
     20     #print(top_k)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py in forward(self, input)
     89     def forward(self, input):
     90         for module in self._modules.values():
---> 91             input = module(input)
     92         return input
     93 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __call__(self, *input, **kwargs)
    489             result = self._slow_forward(*input, **kwargs)
    490         else:
--> 491             result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
    492         for hook in self._forward_hooks.values():
    493             hook_result = hook(self, input, result)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py in forward(self, input)
     53 
     54     def forward(self, input):
---> 55         return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
     56 
     57     def extra_repr(self):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
    992         return torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
    993 
--> 994     output = input.matmul(weight.t())
    995     if bias is not None:
    996         output += bias

RuntimeError: size mismatch, m1: [672 x 224], m2: [672 x 224] at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1524584710464/work/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:249
```

Comment: Is the code you are sharing really the one causing this error (or is this error obtained after trying to fix your model?). The shapes mentioned in the trace don't correspond to the ones in the code...?

Comment: This is what I'm currently getting. The reason the classifier size differs from the error message is because the checkpoint sizes are different. 

If that's incorrect, please let me know and I'll change it

Comment: I am a bit confused. Is it normal that the values in your `checkpoint` dictionary aren't used to configure your actual network? (e.g. your network currently has `500` elements in its hidden layer, not `224`; and similarly its input size should be `3*224*224`, and not `25088` nor `672`)

Comment: Yea, it's strange. The size of the images, when training the classifier, were 224x224. That called for 25088 input size. Now, when we are loading it to predict on test data you would think that the same image size would work for the same input size, but this error keeps coming up.

Comment: Was your question resolved?  Please leave comments to help future viewers, thanks